# Get Typescript typing of returned object

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

### Challenge

Below is a simplified example of how we control and pass data in an app. It is used in many places and works to translate data between UI, APIs, and a database.
API and UI use `camelCase`.
Database uses `snake_case`.

Currently, it's an awkward combination of Partial/Pick types to get some typing where...

```
const item = { fooBar: 'something' }
Item.cast(item).value // returns type Partial<ItemModel>
Item.create(item).value // returns type ItemModel
```

The goal is to return the real returned object type.

```
// Examples
const item = { fooBar: 'something' }
Item.cast(item).value // returns { fooBar: 'something' }
Item.cast(item).databaseFormat // returns { foo_bar: 'something' }
Item.create(item).value // returns { id: '{uuid}', fooBar: 'something' }
Item.create(item).databaseFormat // returns { id: '{uuid}', foo_bar: 'something' }

const itemFromDatabase = { id: '{uuid}', foo_bar: 'something', baz: null }
Item.cast(itemFromDatabase).value // returns { id: '{uuid}', fooBar: 'something', baz: null }
Item.cast(itemFromDatabase).databaseFormat // returns { id: '{uuid}', foo_bar: 'something', baz: null }
```

Any ideas on this? I would image it's something like the Object.entries() return type but I can't figure out that right `T keyof` combination.

```
// https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript
interface ObjectConstructor {
  // ...
  entries<T extends { [key: string]: any }, K extends keyof T>(o: T): [keyof T, T[K]][];
  // ...
}
```

### Code

```
import camelcaseKeys from 'camelcase-keys'
import snakecaseKeys from 'snakecase-keys'

type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<Partial<T>, K> & Omit<T, K>

interface ItemModel {
  id: string
  fooBar: any
  baz?: number
}

interface ItemDatabaseModel {
  id: string
  foo_bar: any
  baz?: number
}

export class Item {

  private _data: Partial<ItemModel>

  public static cast(item: Partial<ItemModel | ItemDatabaseModel>): Item {
    return new this(camelcaseKeys(item))
  }

  public static create(item: Optional<ItemModel | ItemDatabaseModel, 'id'>): Item {
    // Use item.id or add item.id === null to force key
    return new this(camelcaseKeys(item))
  }

  private constructor(input: Partial<ItemModel>) {
    // Validate "input" properties have a Item class property setter, else throw
    // foreach => this[key] = input[key]
  }

  get databaseFormat() { return snakecaseKeys(this._data) }
  get value() { return this._data }

  set id(value: string | null) {
    // automatically generate an ID if null, otherwise validate
    this._data.id = value
  }
  set fooBar(value: any) {
    // validate
    this._data.fooBar = value
  }
  set baz(value: number | null) {
    // validate
    this._data.baz = value
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to have typescript infer what keys you will have on an any arbitrary type of object after it has been put through a function to convert those keys?

Comment: @OliverRadini, yes! That is the better way to phrase it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you could achieve this would be to have some tool which goes through your typescript files looking to type/interface definitions and automatically outputs additional types with the converted keys based on what it finds.

At the moment typescript doesn't support this kind of conversion automatically via a type definition and I'd guess that they'd be quite cautious about adding something like that; concatenating string literals in type definitions is something which has yet to make it into the language, for instance, and what you're looking for here is quite a bit more complex than that, unfortunately.